# Save image file in sdcard in firefox OS

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

I am trying to save an image in sdcard. I am following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Device_Storage) documentation.

```
$('.btnSave').on('click', function () {

        var imageRawData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png") ;
        var sdcard = navigator.getDeviceStorage("sdcard");
        var file = new Blob([imageRawData], { type: "image/png" });
        var request = sdcard.addNamed(file, "FilertedImage.png");

                request.onsuccess = function () {
                var name = this.result;
                console.log('File "' + name + '" successfully wrote on the sdcard storage area');

                }
                request.onerror = function (e) {
                console.log('Unable to write the file: ' + e.target.error.name);

                }
    });
```

In the documentation I found that **"pictures only accepts Blob with a valid [image mime type](http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm)"**. So how can I convert `imageRawData` to valid image mime type using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it like the following - Saves and then shares:

```
 function saveAndSend(blob) {
     var sdcard = navigator.getDeviceStorage("sdcard");
     var request = sdcard.addNamed(blob, "test/mycanvas.png");

     //could just share the blob instead of saving
     request.onsuccess = function () {
         var sharingImage = new MozActivity({
             name: "share",
             data: {
                 type: "image/*",
                 number: 1,
                 blobs: [blob],
                 filenames: ["mycanvas.png"],
                 filepaths: ["test/mycanvas.png"]
             }
         });
     }

     // An error could occur if a file with the same name already exist
     request.onerror = function () {
         alert('Unable to write the file: ' + this.error.name);
     }

 }


 var cnv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
 cnv.toBlob(function (blob) {

     //var sdcard = navigator.getDeviceStorage("pictures");
     var sdcard = navigator.getDeviceStorage("sdcard");
     var request = sdcard.delete("test/mycanvas.png");
     //try to delete in case it exists
     request.onsuccess = function () {
         saveAndSend(blob);
     }

     request.onerror = function () {
         saveAndSend(blob);
     }


 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have visited your profile and saw that you have answered many question of firefox os. Great man!!!!!. So another request ... please have a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682254/how-can-i-share-image-in-facebook-in-firefox-of-using-javascript . I need this.

Comment: I looked at that question.  What error did you get with Adam's approach.

Comment: Actually I want to what will be the values for app domain, platform for packaged app.

Comment: On that question he posted a link to a github example: https://github.com/lukasz-madon/heroesgenerator  With that example and a packaged app you will most likely need to use the orign tag in the manifest.  Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest#origin

Comment: What will be the value of origin tag for me? I have tried app://atishkumarphotofilter.com but facebook did not accept.

Comment: See details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781623/facebook-app-configuration-for-firefox-ospackaged-app

Comment: I will try to create an example and post it

Answer (score 1):

Your app also need to make sure that it has the appropriate device storage permissions.

See: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/dev_apps/ds-test/manifest.webapp#L13 for an example. ds-test is a test app I wrote for testing things in device storage.