# How can I share image in facebook in firefox of using javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, share, firefox-os

I have an image generated from canvas.

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Now I want to share it in facebook. How can I do it for firefox os using javascript.
I am very new. I search a lot but unfortunately I did not get any results.

Comment: Can you give more details? I think what you're trying to say, is: I want to upload the `base64` image from the canvas to my Facebook wall, right? there's 2 ways I think, 1- upload to image to a free hosting image service via API (which allows base64) like imgur, 2- upload it directly to Facebook using https://coderwall.com/p/4qpmfw or BLOB (you can search SO for them)

Comment: I have downloaded the codes but not working.

Answer (score -1):

To share your image is recommended to use the WebActivities allowing you to interact with other applications, for example, share a picture or text ...

Below I leave a simple code to implement it and share your image, you must specify that it is an image and pass it as a blob.

```
blobCanvas.width = imgToShare.width;
blobCanvas.height = imgToShare.height;

// Get context and draw image
var blobCanvasContext = blobCanvas.getContext("2d");
blobCanvasContext.drawImage(imgToShare, 0, 0);

// Export to blob and share through a Web Activitiy
blobCanvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
    new MozActivity({
        name: "share",
        data: {
            type: "image/*",
            number: 1,
            blobs: [blob]
        }
    });
});
```

I recommend you read more about [WebActivities in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Activities)