# Facebook app configuration for Firefox os(packaged app)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, firefox-os

I am developing a firefox os packaged app. For my app what will be the values of red marked portions. Please see the following picture.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to put the URL of your application if it's a hosted one or the URL of your website for App Domains. As for the platform, choose the website. Let me know if it's working.

Comment: App is not hosted. It's packaged app.

Comment: Try with your website even if it's a package application.